# Drop-down list box not displaying chinese characters

Tags: cjk

The Drop-down list box does not display chinese characters in IE 7. Where as Firefox and Safari display correctly. Please let me know how can we correct it in IE 7? Below is the link to the html page I am refering to.

[dropdown-test.html](http://shivanand.in/forums/dropdown-test.html)

Comment: I am using IE7 works fine for me.

Comment: i can see the Chinese characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use the decimal form (`&#...;`) to encode the Chinese symbols, this can't be an encoding problem. My guess is that you don't have a font with Chinese characters installed or that IE 7 can't find it for some reason.

Can you make sure that `Tahoma` is actually installed? If it isn't then FF and Safari might be smarter to select a replacement font than IE 7. Also try `Arial` font and make sure you have the [Asian language pack](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/list/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.vsnet.servicepacks&tid=eb02c9ee-32e2-46e4-9a12-5a72c9f41a19&p=1) from MS installed (see one of the last posts for links).

Comment: Is it the full unicode version? I'm not sure that there is a version of Tahoma out there which doesn't contain all the unicode characters but maybe there is and FF detects this and uses a different font for the Chinese.

Comment: I have installed files for East Asian languages. It works now. Thanks!